# Project structure for Blazor project with Rest Api

Tags: blazor

The questions are related to a school project.

We have among others the following requirements:

1. "The application must have a web front-end for users to interact with the application using a browser"
2. A REST API exposing (a suitable subset of) the business logic must be provided

We have free choice of technology and I would like to use this as an oppurtunity to learn more about Blazor. What would be the recommended way of organizing a project in Blazor with both front end and API (contaiing only a subset of the business logic)?

I guess the API and front end can be implemented in the same project using Blazor server? But maybe it is better to have separate projects, and have the front-end (Blazor wasm?) use the api?

All input highly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/hassanhabib/OtripleS

Comment: Given your requirements you might want to use Blazor WASM instead. Visual studio provide a good solution template to implement Blazor WASM with ASP NET Core Hosted projects. It consist of 3 basic projects. 1. MyWebApplication.Client for front end wasm. 2. MyWebApplication.Server for backend web api. 3. MyWebApplication.Shared for shared items for both front end and backend like viewmodels, interfaces, enums.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question in case someone else are in the same situation.
I started out with Blazor WASM hosted (`dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted`) as [suggested by iamrafael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622403/project-structure-for-blazor-project-with-rest-api/69872623#comment123080390_69622403). This was a good match for my requirements. If you need authentication/authorization I would include that in the scaffolding from the beginning.

I later found and switched to the template from
[Blazor Hero](https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture), which seems like an excellent starting point for a clean architecture using Blazor wasm and asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using WASM project. After creating a Blazor WASM project, I typically restructure it for better organization by dividing the client project into three distinct parts:

1. **Client/UI**: This is the original Blazor WASM project that contains components, pages, and other related elements.
2. **Services**: This is a Class Library containing all the logic for processing server requests and responses, which includes caching, state management, and data presentation. The Services library functions as a regular Class Library.
3. **Network**: Another Class Library dedicated to handling REST calls.

The Client Blazor app depends on the Services library, while the Services library relies on the Network library. This arrangement establishes a clear hierarchy among the components.

Please check the ASP.NET + Blazor starting app I maintain on GitHub: https://github.com/devInstance/DevCoreApp/tree/blazor-app.
It can provide you with some ideas how to structure Server project and Data Access Layer as well.

Check my article about steps by step designing APIS: https://blog.devinstance.net/a-practical-guide-to-aspnet-applications-designing-robust-crud-webapis-part2

Additionally, you may find my latest article on using Mocks in Blazor WASM project during the UI building phase interesting: https://blog.devinstance.net/implementing-a-mock-driven-approach-in-blazor-applications